# Typing for specific json format

Tags: typescript

I am working with a [CastleDB](http://castledb.org/) file and want to correctly type it. CastleDB stores its information in a specific json format. Simplified it looks like this:

```json
{
    "sheets": [
        {
            "name": "firstSheet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "typeStr": "0",
                    "name": "id"
                },
                {
                    "typeStr": "1",
                    "name": "desc"
                }
            ],
            "lines": [
                {
                    "id": "OBJECT_ID1",
                    "desc": "First object. This is  string as defined by 'typeStr: 1'. The 'id' property has id type defined by 'typeStr: 0'. "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

First thing I did was put the entire cdb file into a .ts file and mark it `as const` to allow static type checking for literals. I don't want to change the data at runtime so this isnt an issue. Then I wanted to define a function `getSheet(sheetName): Sheet` that returns the correct sheet type, by default TS just throws the columns and lines of all sheets together and marks columns/lines that aren't on every sheet object as optional, I want to have a type for each sheet instead.

The closest I got is this:

```
type SheetName<I extends number> = typeof data.sheets[I]["name"];
type Sheet<I extends number> = typeof data.sheets[I];

function getSheet<I extends number>(sheetName: SheetName<I>): Sheet<I> {
    const sheet = data.sheets.find(s => s.name === sheetName);
    return sheet as Sheet<I>;
}

getSheet<2>("tech")
```

This works, but requires the number of the sheet, even though the logical key is the `name`. If the generic `I` is omitted, it can't type the sheet at all. Is there a way to use `name` as the key for getting the correct sheet type?

On a side note I am not sure my approach is a good one in general as it may be hitting the limits of ts for more complex column types (Some columns can be enums or objects). So I wonder if generating typescript definitions when compiling might be easier. I just wasn't able to find good documentation on how to do it.